# MVC4 - File download on iPad (instead of showing in browser)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-mobile

Is it possible to download a file using MVC4 to iPad instead of showing the  file in the browser when clicked?

On my webpage, I am showing a table of files (can be any type) and when clicked on the file names, the file should be downloaded to the iPad.

I am using:

```
    Public Sub GetItem(ByVal fileId As Guid)
  Dim sDirectory As String = Commands.Folder.MapFullPath(fileId)
  sDirectory = ApplyClusterServerHACK(sDirectory)

  Me.HttpContext.Response.Clear()
  Me.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"
  Me.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" & System.IO.Path.GetFileName(sDirectory))
  Me.HttpContext.Response.TransmitFile(sDirectory)
  Me.HttpContext.Response.End()

End Sub
```

to get the file and it's working perfectly in desktop browsers. It is prompting if I want to open it or save it, and choosing save opens up the location dialog box where I can select where to save it.

Can this be done in an iPad? If not, do you have any alternate idea how to make it work? Using the Back button on the browser is off-limits since I am running the application full-screen using a "stub" without any menu bars.

Comment: You need an approved app to do this.  I don't think the iPad's security protocols allow downloading of content in this manner without it being through an approved app.

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: An example of an approved app that lets you download files?  GoodReader.